# How to weigh a precomputed effect estimate according to its sample size in a meta-analysis?

Tags: meta-analysis, biostatistics, standardization

I am currently conducting a meta-analysis in R with the intent to pool a standardized metric (i.e. defined daily dose (DDD) per 1000 inhabitant days) into a single forest plot. None of the studies reported the raw DDD and inhabitant-days, but instead reported the calculated DDD/1000 inhabitant days and the total sample size. Based on the available data, I think the analysis is similar to a meta-analysis of incidence rate. Is this correct? However, as the studies did not report raw estimates, we can't use the `metarate` function in R. Is there a way for us to weigh the precomputed standardized metric according to the sample size, and pool them into a single meta-analysis?

**UPDATE:**
As the metric is standardizer to 'per 1 day', I assumed that the number of patients times 1 day corresponds to the person-time. Let's say that I have 50 DDD/1000 inhabitants/day and 100 samples, then the person-time will be 100.

Then, I estimated the SE using the following formula: `SE = sqrt(DDD/(person-time)^2)`, so based on the formula the sample values above will have a SE of 0.070710678.

Is the above assumption and approach correct?

Thank you very much in advance